# How can I make auto-hide/show feature for the dock activate a few millimeters above the bottom?

Tags: macos, dock

I like the auto-hide/show feature for the dock but I don't like how I have to go all the way to the bottom of my screen in order for the auto-show to activate.  Is there a way I can get it to auto-show a few millimeters above the bottom of the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

What you see is what you get, unfortunately. I think it is baked into the UI and is not user modifiable.